# Eclipse shows errors until I clean

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

[image]

This is starting to drive me crazy. I'm developing an android project and as one might expect, I make errors every once in a while. Eclipse shows me the errors in the "Markers" panel. The problem is, when I fix the errors, they don't disappear from the panel. If I try to debug, it tells me my application has errors and I need to fix them.

If I select Project -> Clean, all the errors disappear. This, however, is starting to become a real pain when I have to do it every few minutes.

I have Build Automatically checked, and when I save I wait a few seconds to make sure everything has had time to adjust, but the errors remain.

Anyone else having this problem? Anyone know a fix?

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722
ADT:  20.0.0.v201206242043-391819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: This has been fixed in ADT 20.0.1, so please update your Eclipse plugin.

---

This is a [bug in Android Lint](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33985) in ADT 20. It "holds" Java related errors from the JDT, if you hit the save button at a time where a Java syntax error is present.

You can hit the "Remove all warnings" button in the Android Lint view to get rid of those wrong warnings. Lint will re-create the correct warnings during the next run. If you really get that problem every some minutes, your best bet is to disable Android Lint until the next release (the bug has been fixed in the ADT developer build).

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue. I can either do what you suggested -or- right click on the project and choose Android Tools > Run Lint -or- I can cut the line and repaste it. So it's clear this was an issue with the Lint integration. I'll try what you suggested about updating Android Developer Tools. I currently have 20.0.0, so that may be it.

Comment: I believe that is the issue. I upgraded a few days ago and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your project is corrupted. Try to generate a new one and add to it all the files again.

Comment: What's the problem with my answer?

Comment: It's like telling someone with a leaky faucet to buy a new house. I'm looking for something that addresses this problem specifically.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is 
common prob with eclipse.
Some time it happens that you need to clean the project. But after restarting/installing eclipse problem can be overcome..
But it is common prob.

Comment: It would be great if people didn't just randomly recommend restarting/reinstalling something when there's an actual issue which that won't solve.

We can't answer EVERY question here with "turn it off and on again" :)

Comment: Why not, If the same issue faced by someone and it got solved after restarting Eclipse, Why not it can be suggested to one facing the same thing..

Comment: While I appreciate that its something I can do that might make the problem disappear temporarily, I wouldn't quite call it a solution.